# Monomorphisms and epimorphisms in Ab

Tags: category-theory, abelian-groups

I have a rather simple question though I couldn't find the answer here. Do monomorphisms (epimorphisms) have left (right) inverses in the category of abelian groups? How can we prove this fact knowing that the kernel (cokernel) must be trivial in this case? Will be also glad just for the link with the proof.

Comment: Monomorphisms which have left inverses are called *split monomorpisms* (dually for epimorphisms).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$f:\Bbb Z\to\Bbb Z$ given by $f(a)=2a$ has no left inverse.

The projection $\pi:\Bbb Z\to \Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$ has no right inverse.

Comment: Thanks a lot. My mistake was that I tried to prove it but I had to try to find these nice examples!